# Nlog with .NET core- How to log JSON object without the message

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, nlog

I am using Nlog with .NET core and dependency injection to log JSON objects.
my logs currently look like  : `{"log":{"rersourceId": "2"}} {"log":{"rersourceId": "423"}}` and I want my logs to be printed as simple JSON objects without the message/property name field : `{"rersourceId": "2"}{"rersourceId": "423"}`

Here is my Nlog.config:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="C:\\Data\\LogFiles\\ScheduleVisits\\logging_api\\NLog.log">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>

  </extensions>
  <variable name="LogBaseFolder" value="C:\\Data\\LogFiles\\ScheduleVisits\\logging_api" />
  <targets>



    <target name="ScheduleVisitsLogAsyncWrapper"
            xsi:Type="AsyncWrapper"
            batchSize="200"
            queueLimit="200000"
            timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0">

      <target
        name="ScheduleVisitsLog"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${LogBaseFolder}\\${uppercase:${level}}\\${shortdate}.json"
        archiveAboveSize="10485760"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        createDirs="True"
        encoding="utf-8"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName ="${LogBaseFolder}\\Archive\\${uppercase:${level}}\\ScheduleVisitsAll_{#####}.zip"
        archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
        enableArchiveFileCompression="True">
        <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="True" suppressSpaces="True">
          <attribute name="properties" layout="${json-event-properties}" encode="false"/>
        </layout>
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*"
        minlevel="Trace"
        writeTo="ScheduleVisitsLogAsyncWrapper">
      <filters>
        <when condition="starts-with('${logger}','Microsoft.')" action="Ignore" />
      </filters>
    </logger>

  </rules>
</nlog>
```

In my Program.cs I added these lines in the 'Main' method:

```cs
var factory = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.JsonConverter = new JsonNetSerializer();
var logger = factory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

my appSettings.json file:

```
{

  "Environment": 1,
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is how I log the properties

```
_logger.LogInformation("{log}", input);
```

I must add a message as the first argument to `LogInformation` and I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of: https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/668

Comment: Have yoiu considered just creating your own custom extension methods for `ILogger` that hides away the first argument?

Comment: You can also create your own custom LogState-object that implements IReadOnlyList: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging#logtstate-simple

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the placeholder from `{log}` to `{@resourceId}` and log that property: (don't forget @ sign)

```
_logger.LogInformation("{@resourceId}{@anotherResourceId}", input.YourResourceIdProperty, input.AnotherResourceIdProperty);
```

I am not sure but you may also need to remove the line below from your `nlog.config` file:

```
<attribute name="properties" layout="${json-event-properties}" encode="false"/>
```

Also you can have a look to my answer at a similar post here:
[How to log message without even properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823205/how-to-log-message-without-even-properties/58561373#58561373)

Answer (score 0):

What is `${json-event-properties}` ?

Have you tried to enable `maxRecursionLimit="10"` like this:

```
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="True" suppressSpaces="True" maxRecursionLimit="10">
    </layout>
```

Or like this:

```
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" suppressSpaces="True">
           <attribute name="properties" encode="false">
               <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="True" suppressSpaces="True" maxRecursionLimit="10" />
           </attribute>
    </layout>
```