# How to log message without event properties

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using Nlog v4.6.7 and render messages with the following layout (in Nlog.config).

```
 <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
      <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,fff}" />
      <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
      <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
 </layout>
```

A typical logging is `_logger.Info("Start {job} with {@data}", job, new {a,b,c});`

I use the `includeAllProperties` option since each message may define different properties and I cannot pre-include them one by one as attributes in the layout.

What ends to be printed by the above is something like:

`{ "timestamp": "2019-09-06 13:13:40,386", "level": "Info", "message": "Start \"SomeJobType\" with {\"a\":\"aa\", \"b\":\"bb\", \"c\":\"cc\"}", "job": "SomeJobType", "data": { "a": "aa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc" } }`

Is there a way to disengage the message printed from the event-properties? Thus, 
 achieve something like

`{ "timestamp": "2019-09-06 13:13:40,386", "level": "Info", "message": "Start action", "job": "SomeJobType", "data": { "a": "aa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc" } }`

The `${message:raw=true}` does not help since it prints the placeholders like

`{ "timestamp": "2019-09-06 13:13:40,386", "level": "Info", "message": "Start {job} with {@data}", "job": "SomeJobType", "data": { "a": "aa", "b": "bb", "c": "cc" } }`

Comment: Have you tried to create a loggerEvent?! With that you can edit the attributes and treat them has you want.

Comment: Instead of using `${message}` then you can use `${message:raw=true}`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#nlog-layout-support

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thank you for the tip, but as I wrote in the message this solution is not the one I am looking for since if prints the placeholders.

Comment: @PedroBrito Actually, my code ends up logging a NLog.LogEventInfo which accepts a lsit of MessageTemplateParameter. I didn't use it in the first place since I wanted to know if there is a more by-the-book solution. However, I think that I'll give it a try.

Comment: The MessageTemplateParameter-constructor is a special optimization for integration with the Message Parser in Microsoft Extension Logging. Consider just using `LogEventInfo.Properties` (See my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

You can always do this:

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
var theEvent = new NLog.LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Info, null, "Start action");
theEvent.Properties["job"] = job;
theEvent.Properties["data"] = new {a,b,c};
logger.Log(theEvent);
```

And then configure `MaxRecursionLimit=1` on [JsonLayout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout):

```
 <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="1">
      <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,fff}" />
      <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
      <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
 </layout>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line below from your `nlog.config` file:

```
<attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
```

Then you can print any object you want, just like this:

```
_logger.LogInformation("{@myAnonymous}{@myOtherObject}", new 
{ 
   prop1 = "abc", 
   prop2 = 123,
   nested = 
   {
      nestedProp = true
   }
}, myAnyTypeOfObject);
```

Your log output will look like this (JSON beautified view):

```
{
    "myAnonymous": {
        "prop1 ": "abc",
        "prop2": 123,
        "nested": {
            "nestedProp": true
        }
    },
    "myOtherObject": /*JSON representation of myAnyTypeOfObject object.*/
}
```

Hope this helps.